# MKMapView zoom to users location on viewDidLoad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to zoom a map into the user's current location once the view loads, but I'm getting the error "** *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region '**" when the view loads. Please can someone help?

Cheers!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;   
    mapRegion.center.latitude = map.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    mapRegion.center.longitude = map.userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.2;
    mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.2;
    [map setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];   
}
```

Comment: I think more than enough people have tried to show that you don't need to add `[COCOA-TOUCH]` to the title if your question already has the tag.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

did you set `showsUserLocation = YES`? `MKMapView` won't update the location if it is set to `NO`. So make sure of that.

It is very likely that the `MKMapView` object doesn't have the user location yet. To do right, you should adopt `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol and implement `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:`

```
map.delegate = self;

...
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation 
{
    MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;   
    mapRegion.center = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
    mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.2;
    mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.2;

    [mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];
}
```

Comment: The line "map.delegate = self;" has an error saying 'Uknown type of name 'map''. And if I comment this out, the user's location does show (which it always has) but the view isn't zoomed in

Comment: Well... what I meant was to set the `MKMapView`'s delegate appropriately. Isn't `map` the instance of `MKMapView` and where did you try to do this?

Comment: Yay! Dropped the delegate line into viewDidLoad and it works :) Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

As with Deepak's answer, except you could set the span more elegantly:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;   
    mapRegion.center = map.userLocation.coordinate;
    mapRegion.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.2, 0.2);
    [map setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];
}
```

Comment: Would not be even more elegant to wrap the content of your method in a `static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{<code to center map on user here>});`?  The purpose of this would be to ensure that the map only centers on the user's coordinate once (on viewDidLoad) and not continually reset again and again if the user is moving while using the app.

Comment: Not it this case. The code you provide would only run once per application launch.

Answer (score 9):

You don't want to update this stuff inside userDidUpdateLocation if there is the possbility that the user will want to scroll the map. If you put that code in the mentioned method, the user will not be able to scroll the map because the function will be called and center the map back to the current location.

Comment: You can protect against this by wrapping your code with this: `static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{<code to center map on user here>});`

Comment: This was super helpful FYI @BFar.

Answer (score 6):

By far the easiest way is to use mapView.showAnnotations in didUpdateUserLocation:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation!) {
    mapView.showAnnotations([userLocation], animated: true)
}
```

That's all!

MKUserLocation conforms to the MKAnnotation protocol. Pass the userLocation as an array, the showAnnotations method will let the mapView zoom in on a region plus padding spanning the array of MKAnnotations,in this case it's just the userLocation. Works for me.

If you only want to zoom in once, use a initialUserLocation property to check whether the initial property was already set. I don't like using dispatch_once at all for that sort of thing

Comment: I think this is one of the easiest ways.

Answer (score 4):

Here is @Deepak's answer in Swift 3 for iOS 10:

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate
{
    func mapView( _ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation )
    {
        let regionRadius = 400 // in meters
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance( userLocation.coordinate, regionRadius, regionRadius )
        self.mapView.setRegion( coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem that occurs when you use the `didUpdateUserLocation` method, you will not be able to scroll nor zoom to another location. It will keep pointing to your location. 
The best way (that I've tried) is that you need to use the location manager.

In the `viewDidLoad` add the following :

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;;
// showing user location with the blue dot
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

self.mapView.delegate = self;

// getting user coordinates
CLLocation *location = [_locationManager location];
CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate = [location coordinate];


// showing them in the mapView
_mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, 250, 250);

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

this way you could display your location with the zoom that you want.
I hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

......

```
MKCoordinateRegion region =mapView.region;

region.center.latitude = currentLocation.latitude ;
region.center.longitude = currentLocation.longitude;
region.span.longitudeDelta /= 1000.0;
region.span.latitudeDelta /= 1000.0;

[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
[mapView regionThatFits:region];
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the method setUserTrackingMode of MKMapView. Probably the easiest way of tracking the user's location on a MKMapView is

```
[self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
```

That way you also don't need to be a MKMapViewDelegate. The possible modes are:

```
MKUserTrackingModeNone = 0, // the user's location is not followed
MKUserTrackingModeFollow, // the map follows the user's location
MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading, // the map follows the user's location and heading
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 version
Use this method to zoom into any coordinate.

```
extension MKMapView{
    func zoomIn(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, withLevel level:CLLocationDistance = 10000){
        let camera =
            MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenter: coordinate, fromEyeCoordinate: coordinate, eyeAltitude: level)
        self.setCamera(camera, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Deepak, implement the `mapView:didUpdate:` delegate method. Syntax for **Swift 5**:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
  guard let newLocation = userLocation.location else { return }
  let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: newLocation.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2))
  mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `map.userLocation.coordinate`, the rest is OK.