# ios zooming in on users location

Tags: ios, mapkit, core-location, zooming, mkuserlocation

Hi I have set my MapKit up to show users location, but it is loading with a view much too zoomed out, so I am trying to zoom it in to e.g. an area of 20 miles.
I tried to do this using code from some other questions but none of them seem to make any difference to the view what so ever.
Btw I'm also trying to be able to see the current users: latitude and longitude, but only seeing 0 in my float variable, maybe these are linked?

Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER)
    {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
#endif

    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(20.5982f,0.0001f);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = {30, 75};
    MKCoordinateRegion region = {coordinate, span};
    MKCoordinateRegion regionThatFits = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
    [self.mapView setRegion:regionThatFits animated:YES];

    self.locationManager.delegate=self;
   [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    float latitude = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
    float longitude = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;

    [self.mapView.userLocation addObserver:self
                                forKeyPath:@"location"
                                   options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
                                   context:NULL];
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

Thanks very much for any help you can give with this. I am new to MapKit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MKMapView zoom to users location on viewDidLoad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063970/mkmapview-zoom-to-users-location-on-viewdidload)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks for the pointer, but this didn't solve the issue

Comment: then wat happened , what else u need

Comment: Are you running this in the simulator? To get a real latitude and longitude, you'll have to simulate a location.

Comment: Hi all, yes I am running this in the simulator, but have set it up using: debug/location/custom location. I entered in my lat & long and it is showing my position correctly on the map. The only problem is that the map is too zoomed out. When ever I add some of coding examples I always seem to get the same result, which is nothing, no error, no message. Just the map showing my location but zoomed out still. Is there a problem with the code I have entered above please?

Comment: copy MKMapView+ZoomLevel class in your code and check it,(https://github.com/johndpope/MKMapViewZoom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(30.5982f,0.0001f);
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = {36, 90};
MKCoordinateRegion region = {coordinate, span};
MKCoordinateRegion regionThatFits = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
[self.mapView setRegion:regionThatFits animated:YES];
```